# How to link Listview vertical scrollbar to Scrollviewer scrollbar without placing ListView inside the scrollviewer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, scrollviewer

I have one **ListView** like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="TestLogListView" ItemsSource="{Binding TestLogList}">
    <ListView.View>
       <GridView>
           <GridViewColumn Width="auto" Header="Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ActionType}"/>
           <GridViewColumn Width="auto" Header="Step No." DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=StepNumber}"/>
           <GridViewColumn Width="auto" Header="Element" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Element}"/>
           <GridViewColumn Width="auto" Header="Description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
        </GridView>
     </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

And **ScrollViewer** like this:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="LogMapScrollViewer" ScrollChanged="ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="LogMapStackPanel" Width="0"></StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I am trying to link scrollbars of both of the controls so that if Scrollviewer is scrolled then ListView also scrolled and the other-way-round.
I dont want to place ListView inside a new ScrollViwer because the Gridview header row becomes scrollable.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I don't know why you did the whole `GridView` inside `ListView` thing..but have you tried `Binding` the `ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset` to the `ListView.ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset`?

Comment: @TomerAgmon1, There is no access to these properties in xaml.